# Redux-saga pass query and options for POST body

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to filter the data before displaying it in the React app

Of course, the data arrives well and is displayed correctly, but I am trying to filter it through a field in the database

When I try on Postman via Query everything is done correctly

I will attach a picture of Postman

My question in particular is the following
How do I pass a query or options in saga knowing that it will be sent in the body

[image]

I have tried some solutions, but they are not working for you, as in the attached code

**this saga**

```
function* getServicesSupport() {
    try {
        const response  = yield call(getServicesSupportApi, {query: {categoryTickets : 2}, options: {limit: 3}});
        yield put(ServicesSupportApiResponseSuccess(GET_SERVICES_SUPPORT_LIST, response.data));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(ServicesSupportApiResponseError(GET_SERVICES_SUPPORT_LIST, error));
    }
}
```

**this getServicesSupportApi**

```
  export const getServicesSupportList = () => api.post(url.GET_SERVICES_SUPPORT_LIST);
```

as you have seen in the picture for Postman,

a query was passed as my request is of type post

I'm new to react saga I don't know how to pass a query or options

I know very well how to pass a parameter in the request,

but I do not know how to pass a query

I need to pass more than one query in other requests, filters and sort or populate ....

So it is very important for me to know how to pass query as in

Comment: Can you share the `getServicesSupportApi` function as well?

Comment: @MartinKadlec 'export const getServicesSupportList = () => api.get(url.GET_SERVICES_SUPPORT_LIST);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your api.get supports sending the body/query params, e.g. like `api.get(url.GET_SERVICES_SUPPORT_LIST, {categoryTickets: 2})` you can modify the `call` effect to pass down the values

```js
const getServicesSupportList = (payload) => api.post(url.GET_SERVICES_SUPPORT_LIST, payload);
let response = yield call(getServicesSupportApi, {categoryTickets : 2});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply
Unfortunately it didn't work
I want to know how body/query is passed as in Postman

Comment: @SerijaNada is `api` axios instance?

Comment: Sir, as you saw in the picture for Postman, a query was passed as my request is of type post
I'm new to react saga
I don't know how to pass a query or options
I know very well how to pass a parameter in the request, but I do not know how to pass a query
I hope you understand me now
I need to pass more than one query in other requests, filters and sort
So it is very important for me to know how to pass query as in Psestman

Comment: What about `yield call(getServicesSupportApi, {query: {categoryTickets : 2}, options: {foo: 'bar'}});`